# Getting error trying to use react-native-fbsdk on android

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to add a **Facebook Login** on my **react native** project using **react-native-fbsdk** library, but I am getting error while running `react-native run-android`.

Here's the screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Description]

I have clearly followed the installation instructions from their github repo: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

I tried most of the solutions found on SO but couldn't make it run.

I have following versions installed:

**react-native@0.47.1**

**react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0**

Comment: Can you give more details about the solutions you tried please.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to breaking change in 0.47.1 which affects most of the native dependencies. In case of react-native-fbsdk, they has yet to release new version. So if you use following version, it would be fine.

- react-native : **0.46.4**
- react-native-fbsdk : **0.6.1**

Comment: Yes, I later downgraded the **react-native** to **0.46.4** and it's working now perfectly.

Comment: This is a bit crap, someone would suppose that at least Facebook is keeping their libraries up to date with new releases of React Native.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada Were you able to run this setup on iOS as well? I'm having to keep my fbsdk to 0.6.0 to get it to run on iOS.